# Eclipse Error: Android Library Update error

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to setup development for android using eclipse "Build id: 20120920-0800".
I follow instructions on developer.Android.com how to set up android with eclipse. I first download the android sdk, oracle java 8, eclipse mobile and install plugins: DDMS, Dev Tools, and the ndk from eclipse Help->"Install New Software". No matter what I Do when I start up eclipse and it loads android projects I get "Android Library Update" error. I've tried deleting and re-installing every thing in different orders. I did find that after installing the NDK I do get the library update error. At one time I was getting C/C++ indexer error but, I do not see that one anymore. So I was wondering if anyone knew what exactly is causing the Library update error. The details about the update error is always

"An internal error occurred during: "Android Library Update".
  java.lang.NullPointerException"

Oh and I have tried multiple solutions from deleting and re-installing android sdk and cleaning the project solution.

Comment: What is Android Library? It seems a bit vague - could mean the sdk library or the project library...

Answer (score 1):

First configure and test Eclipse with AndroidSDK before using the NDK toolchain. Build a sample app to test out your current emulator setup. If you want to build to your phone, connect it to you computer (install the appropriate driver if needed and enable debugging on your phone).

Try this:

- use standard Eclipse (current one - Eclipse Classic 4.2.1)
- download and install the ADT Plugin for Eclipse (make sure you select the *"DeveloperTools"*)
- configure ADT Plugin by selecting AndroidSDK directory
- add an AVD (Android virual device)
- test out your emulator by building and running an app or connect your phone to the computer
- install and configure NDK

And know this:

> In general, you should only use the NDK if it is essential to your
>   app—never because you simply prefer to program in C/C++.

Comment: The Android library is just that. I'm not the vague one here. This is eclipse's answer of what the problem is. Eclipse never give straight forward answers to what the problem is. Oh by the way I did what you said Secko and it definitely is a problem with the NDK. Android Java projects work fine.